# ¿Cómo eliminar una tabla completa en MySQL desde Java?

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy tratando de eliminar una tabla de MySQL completa desde Java NetBeans.

Este es el código que estoy utilizando

```
 public int EliminarTablaHC() {

    int resultado = 0;
    Connection conexion = null;

    String sentencia_crear = (" DROP TABLE hojacarga;");

    try {
        conexion = conexionBD.conectar();
        sentencia_preparada = conexion.prepareStatement(sentencia_crear);
        resultado = sentencia_preparada.executeUpdate();
        sentencia_preparada.close();

        conexion.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);

    }
    return resultado;
     }
```

En el botón que lo ejecuta pongo esto:

```
   int opcion = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Deseas Eliminar la hoja de carga?");
    if (opcion == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        int resultado = 0;
        Connection conexion = null;
        int i = metodos.EliminarTablaHC();

        if (i > 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "hoja de carga Eliminada correctamente");
            
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "La hoja de carga NO fue eliminada");
        }
    }
```

Pero me tira el siguiente error al ejecutarlo:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'sistema.hojacarga'

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la idea de eliminar una y otra vez una tabla? ¿Acaso estás queriendo borrar _un registro de esa tabla_? Además, ¿cuándo verificás si la tabla existe?

Comment: La solución al error que te está dando es primero que nada haber creado la tabla. No puedes borrar una tabla que no existe! De todas maneras... qué sistema más raro que tienes que andar borrando una tabla. Normalmente no hace falta borrar y crear tablas en tiempo de ejecución...

Comment: Aunque no tenga mucho sentido lo que quieres hacer, deberías siempre antes de borrar algo, preguntar si existe. `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hojacarga;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aca te dejo algunas sugerencias para que puedas tomarlas en consideración.

El error podria deberse por varias razones. Una de ellas la tabla que estás tratando de eliminar no existe en la base de datos.

**La tabla no se llama exactamente "hojacarga".
La tabla está en un esquema diferente al que estás conectado.
La tabla ya ha sido eliminada previamente.**

Verifica tu esquema :
Si la tabla está en un esquema diferente al que estás conectado, tienes que especificar el esquema al referenciar la tabla. Por ejemplo, si la tabla está en el esquema "prueba"

**String sentencia_crear = ("DROP TABLE prueba.hojacarga;");**

Espero te sirva, saludos

Comment: Gracias, si me olvide de preguntar si la tabla existe en primer lugar y segundo es la forma de consulta del i>0 que al estar planteado de esta forma siempre me saltaba que no fue borrada pero en realidad si lo hacia asi que modifique ese i>0 por i==0 ademas de validar la existencia

Answer (score 0):

Para eliminar una tabla seria usando la sentencia

```
DROP TABLE nombreBaseDeDatos.nombreTabla;
```

El detalle para que esta sentencia sea efectiva, tienes que tener configurado un usuario que tenga los suficientes permisos para poder eliminar una tabla sino no te lo permitira. Ejm. usar un usuario con los permisos de administrador o el usuario que estas usando añadir el permiso de DROP